# What is a good UI framework for a card game?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I've been constructing a card game and want to use a good UI framework for my client.

I was leaning towards WPF, since I have VS2010 and good experience with C#, but I'm having doubts about it, since it isn't quite tailored towards games.

I'd like to have something that allows me to do nice (but simple) animations for typical card actions, like drawing/discarding/playing etc. I know WPF has better support for animations that WinForms, but will it be enough for a game like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to develop games in WPF, and its animation system was a huge timesaver.  To get the most out of WPF.  I highly recommend using [Microsoft Expresion Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx) for UI design and animation, going back and forth between Blend, and Visual Studio, I was able to build animated interfaces in hours that would have taken days using a more conventional UI framework.  I believe that new versions of blend even let you edit C#, that would be an even bigger time saver.

Comment: +1 Blend is a nice tool, if a bit intimidating.  I also like using it to easily get and edit standard control templates.

Comment: @Wonko the Sane, a lot less intimidating then creating all your keyframes programmatically, or even worse, working with an API that doesn't even provide key frames.

Comment: Oh, agreed.  I just find it "different" (perhaps more of a graphics design program) than what I am used to in Visual Studio.  That being said, it is an invaluable tool, if you can convince those that control the purse strings that you need it, which isn't always the case.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at XNA?
It probably wont be easy to creat the animatons, but the framework itself is geared towards gaming. It's Microsoft tech and all the examples I'v seen are implemented in C#

You could even look at Managed Direct X which itself was the precursor to XNA and is also Microsoft tech.

Answer (score 1):

WPF is certainly capable for something like this.  In fact, [Adam Nathan](http://blog.adamnathan.net/) has an example in his earlier WPF book, "[Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328917)."

There is a .NET 4.0 version, but I haven't actually seen it.  However, the earlier version of the book was quite well done IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll head down to the bookstore this week and take a look at this book.

Comment: No problem.  I will warn you that the older book predates the push to MVVM, and that there have been a number of improvements made to the platform since its publishing.  However, it is still a good general overview of WPF, and I imagine the newer volume addresses these things.